# Switch Statement output data into new Var

Tags: java

I want to know how to get the result from my switch statement into a new variable.

This is my code, once the switch statement finds the correct employee i want this information to go to a new variable. How would i do this?

Also, if I type a Char or String in the Employee number field, how would I get it to return and error instead of crashing the app?

```
package payRoll; // package Name

///////////////////////////////

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

//////////////////// API Imports

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner ( System.in );

    /////////// Code

    String cacheEm = new String();  

    ArrayList<String[]> addresses = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    String[] EmNo  = new String[4]; {
        EmNo[0] = "Shaun Clark";
        EmNo[1] = "Ann Clark";
        EmNo[2] = "Darren Watters";
        EmNo[3] = "Daniel Brightman";

    addresses.add(EmNo);

    }       
    boolean repeat;
    do {
      repeat = false;

    System.out.print("Please Enter Employee number: ");     
    int employeeNum = keyboard.nextInt();   
    switch (employeeNum)
    {       
    case 1: employeeNum = 0;
    System.out.println("Employee Indexed as " + EmNo[0]);
    break;
    case 2: employeeNum = 1;
    System.out.println("Employee Indexed as " + EmNo[1]);
    break;
    case 3: employeeNum = 2;
    System.out.println("Employee Indexed as " + EmNo[2]);
    break;
    case 4: employeeNum = 3;
    System.out.println("Employee Indexed as " + EmNo[3]);
    break;
    default:            
        System.err.println("\n Employee Not found!! \n");
        repeat = true;          
        } 
    }       
    while(repeat);     

    keyboard.close();



    ////// output from switch needs to go into new variable for next function


  }// end class
}// end main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the result in `employeeNum`, just check for it being less than 4 and you're good. Just get `EmNo[employeeNum]` which you should be doing instead of that switch statement anyway...

For catching errors in the input, you should catch the exception being thrown with a try-catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

> Im wanting to know how to get the result from my switch statement into a new variable

You have to declare the `employeeNum` variable outside of the `do-while` loop for you to be able to use it after the loop.

You can put it at the top where you declare your variables:

```
// ...
String cacheEm = new String();  
int employeeNum;
// ...
```

Then you can use it inside the loop:

```
// ...
boolean repeat;
do {
  repeat = false;

System.out.print("Please Enter Employee number: ");     
employeeNum = keyboard.nextInt();    // notice no 'int' because it is already declared at the top of the program
// ... rest of the code
```

> If I type a Char or String in the Employee number field, how would i get it to return and error instead of crashing the app?

There are a few ways of doing this, one way would be to catch the exception for invalid input:

Since you are using the `Scanner.nextInt()` method, this method throws the `InputMismatchException` if the next token does not match the `Integer` regular expression, or is out of range meaning too big of a number. So you can put your code in a `try/catch` and catch this exception and print out the error.

```
// ... 
boolean repeat;
do {
    repeat = false;
    System.out.print("Please Enter Employee number: ");  
    try {
        employeeNum = keyboard.nextInt();  
         switch (employeeNum) {
           // ... rest of your code
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
      System.err.println("Please enter an integer");
      // or you can just print the stack trace like ime.printStackTrace() which is pretty standard
    }
} while(repeat);     
keyboard.close();

// use employeeNum here
```

Another way would be to read the `employeeNum` as a `String` using `Scanner.next()` and then try to parse it as an `int` and catch the `NumberFormatException` if the value isn't an integer:

```
boolean repeat;
do {
    repeat = false;
    System.out.print("Please Enter Employee number: ");  
    try {
        employeeNum = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.next());  
        switch (employeeNum) {
            // ... rest of your code
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
      System.err.println("Please enter an integer");
      // or you can just print the stack trace like nfe.printStackTrace() which is pretty standard
    }
} while(repeat);     
keyboard.close();

// use employeeNum here
```